# Remove string pool

Tags: python, string, string-pool

I want to generate a large string (`20MB`+) every 3 seconds.
Now my problem is that my string pool get larger and larger and i have no `RAM` for that.

Anyone knows how to remove the string pool manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Show some code. It's hard to imagine what are you doing.  20 Mb - is not so big. Are you using `intern`? Why?

Comment: 20mb per 3 seconds